# sql 2016 SSMS Editor is acting weird

Tags: editor, ssms, syntax-highlighting

The highlighting isn't working, the comment and uncomment toolbar buttons are grayed out.  if you click anywhere after a line that is where your cursor is even though there are no real spaces in your line.  I have check tools - options so many times I feel like a poster child for that quote "the definition of insanity is doing the same thing over and over again and expecting a different result"

Editor :
[image: screen]

Version :

[image: screen]

Comment: Did you try to deinstall/install the application?

Comment: yeah tried that didn't work

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/15f4b397-385e-49de-8b75-6221e6420c04/ssms-2016-syntaxhighlighting-is-not-working-properly?forum=sqltools) discussion.

Comment: seen it. I tried that on one of the three servers that this is happening on and it did nothing to resolve my issue